# Программа работает не так, как нужно, в чём дело

Tags: c, windows, файлы, файловая-система, fopen

Вообщем хотела сделать простенькое шифрование файлов с расширением ".txt" , но почему-то он вообще ничего с ними не делает, хотя программа нормально завершается, я до этого указывала в массиве уже имя и расширение файла , которое было на рабочем столе: "1.txt" и он шифровался, а мне хотелось бы , чтобы шифровались все мои файлы с расширением ".txt"

```
char fname[30] = ".txt";
int i;                                              
int keylen;                          
char *filebuff = NULL;

char key[]="ABCDEF";

keylen=strlen(key);   


FILE *fileptr, *dskfileptr;
```

И собственно дальше идёт сам процесс шифрования, проблема в том, что когда я указывала в массив имя и расширение существующего файла, то функция fopen() срабатывала и происходило действие с этим файлом, а если я хочу открыть функцией fopen() все файлы с расширением ".txt" , то это не работает, объясните пожалуйста в чём дело

Comment: ну собственно вы сами и написали почему. fopen принимает имя файла. для поиска по маске можете использовать что-то из серии opendir/readdir

Answer (score 2):

Представим на секунду, что вам это удалось - открыть сразу **все** файлы с расширением `txt`:

```
FILE * f = fopen(".txt","rt");
```

Скажите, что именно будет прочитано в операции, скажем,

```
fscanf(f,"%s",buf);
```

Какой из 2354 файлов будет прочтен?

Надеюсь, теперь вы понимаете, что хотели не просто странного, но и внутренне противоречивого? :)

Вам нужно перебирать все файлы с таким расширением и работать с каждым по отдельности. Намек - смотрите в сторону функций [`findfirst/findnext`](http://www.c-cpp.ru/content/findfirst-findnext) или соответствующих [функций операционной системы](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilea) (если бы вы работали в C++ - там было бы проще благодаря стандартной библиотеке `filesystem`).

Comment: То есть я не смогу произвести операции со всеми файлами, но можно ли как-то обойтись обычной функцией fopen()?

Comment: Просто до меня не доходит, можно ли как-то открывать каждый файл по отдельности и делать с ним уже определённые действия и затем переходить к другим файлам

Comment: @Jessica конечно можно. посмотрите описание функций в ответе.

Comment: Делайте, только не забывайте закрывать открытый файл, переходя к следующему (число одновременно открытых файлов не бесконечно...)

Comment: Можно форкнуть приложение ровно столько раз, сколько файлов, и делать с ними всё, что хочется (почти) одновременно.

Comment: @0andriy Можно. Особенно классно получится, если файлов много, а ядер мало...

Comment: Ну да, это же всё теоретические изыскания :)

Comment: > открыть сразу все файлы с расширением txt - Ахахаха)) Браво!